# SIMD loading indices and gather instruction

Tags: c++, vectorization, simd

I am trying to load 4 (integers) indices into a register and then load the corresponding vector values using a gather instruction. I would like to use a "unaligned" instruction like loadu and AVX2.

```
void func(double* val, size_t* rowptr,int* index, double *x, double *ret, int size)
{ 
   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
       int start = rowptr[i]; int end = rowptr[i+1];   
       __m256d tmp = _mm256_setzero_pd();
       int j;
       for (j = start; j < end; j += 4)
       {
        __m128i vind = _mm_loadu_epi64(&index[j]); <- how can I do that
        __m256d data = _mm256_loadu_pd(&val[j]);
        __m256d xval = _mm256_i64gather_pd(x, vind, 1);

        tmp = _mm256_add_pd(tmp, _mm256_mul_pd(data,xval));
       }
```

I need an instruction to store 4 integer indices into a __m128i register since the gather instruction requires it :

```
extern __m256d _mm256_mask_i64gather_pd(double const * base, __m128i vindex, const int scale);
```

however I haven't been able to find an instruction like _mm_loadu_epi6() that does it.

Comment: So `_mm_loadu_si128`?

Comment: but with si128 we cannot distringuish between  lets say 32 bit integers or 64bits  integers or .. ?

Comment: There is no distinction to make anyway, 128 bits is 128 bits

Comment: sadly this yields a "can’t convert between vector values of different size" error...strange, the vector are both 128 bits

Comment: Shouldn't that gather be `_mm256_i32gather_pd`?

Comment: absolutely, thank you !